# jQuery finding descendant by ID not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the value of a jQuery datepicker input element in a form to the first date in the week of the user-selected date once the submit button is clicked but before the form is actually submitted.

I'm finding that the following Javascript works (using a class selector in `.find()`):

```
$("form").submit( function(event) {
    $(this).closest('form').find('.week-picker').datepicker( "setDate", startDate );
    var current_date = $(this).closest('form').find('.week-picker').datepicker( "getDate" );
    return;
});
```

`startDate` is a Date object.

But this code does not work (using an ID selector in `.find()`):

```
$("form").submit( function(event) {
    $(this).closest('form').find("#week-picker").datepicker( "setDate", startDate );
    var current_date = $(this).closest('form').find('.week-picker').datepicker( "getDate" );
    return;
});
```

`console.log($(this).closest('form').find(".week-picker").datepicker( "setDate", startDate ).val());` produces a proper date, like `06/27/2018`.

`console.log($(this).closest( 'form' ).find('#week-picker').val());` produces `undefined`.

**Why is this happening? Isn't an ID a valid selector?**

HTML:

```
<form action="/checkin" method="post">     
    <div class="form-group row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <input class="week-picker form-control" type="text" id="week-picker" name="week_start" placeholder="Select week" style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">
         </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mt-4">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The datepicker portion of my JS:

```
var startDate;
var endDate;

var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
                }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $(this).closest( 'form' ).find('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings ));
            $(this).closest( 'form' ).find('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate( dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings ));
                    selectCurrentWeek();
         },
         beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                    var cssClass = '';
                    if(date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                        cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
                    return [true, cssClass];
         },
         onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
                    selectCurrentWeek();
         }
     });

   $(document).on( 'mousemove','.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr',function() {$(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
   $(document).on('mouseleave','.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr',function() {$(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
```

Comment: Can you post the code for this input as you find it in the element inspector? JS might be modifying it after loading.

Comment: What does `$(this).closest("form").find("#week-picker").selector` or `$(this).closest("form").find("#week-picker")[0]` return?

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz `<input class="week-picker form-control hasDatepicker" type="text" name="week_starting" placeholder="Select week to start tracking" id="dp1529862475978">`

Comment: @Xufox both return `undefined`

Comment: Try removing `.closest("form")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#week-picker` is a valid selector, as long as your input has that ID assigned. What is happening in your case is that there is JS turning your input into a datepicker, and it changes the ID of the element when it loads. As you posted from your element inspector, your input no longer has the `week-picker` ID, it is now `dp1529862475978`.

This is not uncommon, and the behavior you're getting is the expected one. If you need to make sure that you're targeting this datepicker instead of another one with the same class, you can use the name attribute:

```
$("input[name='week_starting']")
```

You should never have 2 inputs with the same name on the same page, so it's as unique as an ID. The ID you're seeing in the element inspector is probably randomly generated, so you don't want to use that.

Comment: It would be useful for others reading this post if you could add some info about the JS you're using for the datepicker, so that it will show up in searches.